# pyspark 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to run some code, but getting error:

> 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'

The code:

```
items = [(1,12),(1,float('Nan')),(1,14),(1,10),(2,22),(2,20),(2,float('Nan')),(3,300),
         (3,float('Nan'))]

sc = spark.sparkContext
rdd = sc.parallelize(items)
df = rdd.toDF(["id", "col1"])

import pyspark.sql.functions as func
means = df.groupby("id").agg(func.mean("col1"))

# The error is thrown at this line
df = df.withColumn("col1", func.when((df["col1"].isNull()), means.where(func.col("id")==df["id"])).otherwise(func.col("col1")))
```

Comment: You can't use a second dataframe inside a function like this - use a join instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't reference a second spark DataFrame inside a function, unless you're using a join. IIUC, you can do the following to achieve your desired result.

Suppose that `means` is the following:

```python
#means.show()
#+---+---------+
#| id|avg(col1)|
#+---+---------+
#|  1|     12.0|
#|  3|    300.0|
#|  2|     21.0|
#+---+---------+
```

Join `df` and `means` on the `id` column, then apply your `when` condition

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import when

df.join(means, on="id")\
    .withColumn(
        "col1",
        when(
            (df["col1"].isNull()), 
            means["avg(col1)"]
        ).otherwise(df["col1"])
    )\
    .select(*df.columns)\
    .show()
#+---+-----+
#| id| col1|
#+---+-----+
#|  1| 12.0|
#|  1| 12.0|
#|  1| 14.0|
#|  1| 10.0|
#|  3|300.0|
#|  3|300.0|
#|  2| 21.0|
#|  2| 22.0|
#|  2| 20.0|
#+---+-----+
```

But in this case, I'd actually recommend using a [`Window`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Window) with [`pyspark.sql.functions.mean`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.mean):

```python
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, mean

df.withColumn(
    "col1",
    when(
        col("col1").isNull(), 
        mean("col1").over(Window.partitionBy("id"))
    ).otherwise(col("col1"))
).show()
#+---+-----+
#| id| col1|
#+---+-----+
#|  1| 12.0|
#|  1| 10.0|
#|  1| 12.0|
#|  1| 14.0|
#|  3|300.0|
#|  3|300.0|
#|  2| 22.0|
#|  2| 20.0|
#|  2| 21.0|
#+---+-----+
```

Answer (score -5):

I think you are using Scala API, in which you use ().
In PySpark, use [] instead.