# Trying to load messages from Azure Service Bus to ADLS with Apache Spark Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, azureservicebus, azure-databricks

I am trying to move messages in Azure Service Bus queues to ADLS with Databricks.

The code that I'm using is as follows:

```
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient, ServiceBusMessage

CONNECTION_STR = "Endpoint=sb://carlsbus.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=2BIOtFdooJFIkhZF0qxtYEoK32hJa39DseStw="

QUEUE_NAME = "myqueue"

servicebus_client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=CONNECTION_STR, logging_enable=True)

receiver = servicebus_client.get_queue_receiver(queue_name=QUEUE_NAME, max_wait_time=5)
```

And when I execute the following:

```
mystream2 = spark.readStream.format(receiver).load("/mnt/lake/RAW/FormulaClassification/F1Area/F1Domain/flightStream/1")
```

But I keep on getting the error:

```
'ServiceBusReceivedMessage' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'
```

Any thoughts why I'm getting the error?

Comment: FYI if that's your actual key in the connection string, I recommend re-generating that key, since it's now been published here.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for reaching out about the key - I made sure to post a dummy key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error - 'ServiceBusReceivedMessage' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'

Above error occurs when you try to use dataframe inside a function. In your case you have used `receiver` inside `format()` function.

You can not use dataframe inside function.

For more information Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57363618/pyspark-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-get-object-id) SO thread and this [article](https://cumsum.wordpress.com/2020/10/10/pyspark-attributeerror-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-_get_object_id/)

Comment: Rather than posting an answer that links to another answer, just vote to close this question as a duplicate of the one you referenced (it's basically the same thing). The OP would still see the link to that other answer (and associated question).

Comment: @David, point taken  .How do I vote to close this question as duplicate

Comment: @Patterson - not really something you can do, as you wrote the question - I was really commenting on the person who posted this answer, that the more effective thing to do is to flag your question as a duplicate (that's not a bad thing). Hopefully the other question's answer provides what you need.

Comment: @Patterson - looks like my advice was a bit off anyway - close-votes (including marking as duplicates) requires at least 3,000 reputation (though the question can be flagged for review, with far less rep).